# Apagar o último valor em um array

Tags: ruby

Tenho um array em que cada índice consta uma letra, que juntas formam uma frase. Eu não estava conseguindo de forma alguma apagar o **último** valor do array. Após pesquisar bastante, consegui apagar, porém estou achando que o código está muito "tapa buraco". Olhem como tentei da primeira vez:

```
p "Primeiro teste:"
array = ["t", "e", "s", "t", "e", "_", "t", "e", "s", "t", "e"]

array.delete(array.last)
```

Obviamente ele vai deletar todos os "e" do array. Então, aqui estão minhas tentativas:

```
p "Segundo teste:"
array = ["t", "e", "s", "t", "e", "_", "t", "e", "s", "t", "e"]

// Retorna o index último item do último elemento do array
array.delete_at(array.rindex(array.last))
```

A outra:

```
p "Terceiro teste:"
array = ["t", "e", "s", "t", "e", "_", "t", "e", "s", "t", "e"]

// Inverte o array, deleta o primeiro elemento e inverte novamente
array.reverse!.shift.reverse!
```

Todos os códigos rodando: http://repl.it/knV

Alguma forma mais eficiente e limpa de fazer o trabalho? Não achei uma função específica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Também pode-se usar o método [`pop()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-pop)

```
array = ["t", "e", "s", "t", "e", "_", "t", "e", "s", "t", "e"]
p array

array.pop()
p "Deletando"
p array

# ["t", "e", "s", "t", "e", "_", "t", "e", "s", "t", "e"]
# "Deletando:"
# ["t", "e", "s", "t", "e", "_", "t", "e", "s", "t"]
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/6AMvhV)</kbd>

Comment: Perfeito! Tenho uma leve impressão de que já tinha testado esse comando antes, porém na hora não sei o motivo de não ter funcionado. Obrigado :)